# Self-Assignment in ANSI C

Tags: c, embedded, iar, ansi-c

I am currently working on a embedded C project and I "inherited" some old code containing statements such as:

```
rxStruct = rxStruct;
```

where rxStruct is a variable.

What could be the use of such statements?

Comment: It could have something to do with memory mapped device I/O.  Context is important here, nobody can guess at this from a single line of code.

Comment: Could also be a crude way to add code/instructions to break on. I.e. act as place to set a breakpoint. I’ve seen that in colleagues’ code. Hans’ suggestion is also very plausible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Without further information, one use of such a statement is to prevent an unused parameter compiler warning if `rxStruct` is passed in as a parameter and then otherwise not used.

Comment: A better way to do it: `(void)rxStruct`. Usually you should use a define: `#define UNUSED(X) (void)X`.